# How do I get make the in_memory adapter of the the ruby library DataMapper to save the model's id properly?

Tags: ruby, datamapper, in-memory

This regards the ruby ORM library [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/doku.php).

[This wiki](http://datamapper.org/doku.php?id=docs:misc#in-memory_adapter) describes how to use the in_memory adapter for DataMapper. The proper database adapters saves an incrementing, unique id on each model instance - in_memory doesn't seem to do that as shown by the following snippet:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'dm-core'

DataMapper.setup(:in_memory, :adapter => 'in_memory')

class Foo
    include DataMapper::Resource

    def self.default_repository_name;:in_memory;end
    def self.auto_migrate_down!(rep);end
    def self.auto_migrate_up!(rep);end
    def self.auto_upgrade!(rep);end

    property :id, Serial
    property :name, Text
end

f = Foo.new
f.name = "foo"
f.save

puts f.inspect
```

The results of the inspect is:

```
#<Foo id=nil name="foo">
```

Had I used another adapter to connect to, for instance, a sqlite database *id* would've been set to '1'.

I would like to refer to my models via id, because I can't guarantee uniqueness on other attribuets. Is there a way of making the in_memory adapter save an incrementing, unique id attribute for its models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, auto-incrementing is not supported for the DM in-memory adapter (I suspect that adapter doesn't get much love) but you could fake it pretty easily:

```
before :save, :increment_id
def increment_id
  self.id ||= begin
    last_foo = (Foo.all.sort_by { |r| r.id }).last
    (last_foo ? last_foo.id : 0).succ
  end
end
```

I don't think I'd recommend this though.  One probably much better alternative would be to use a SQLite in-memory database instead.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what your exact issue was, but this issue is now fixed - your example script works with DataMapper 1.0.2. Further, the correct syntax now is:

```
require 'dm-core'

DataMapper.setup(:default, :adapter => 'in_memory')

class Foo
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :name, Text
end

f = Foo.new
f.name = "foo"
f.save

puts f.inspect
```

Contrary to Bob's answer, the in-memory adapter is a first class citizen that is kept up to date and documented, because it is used extensively in the test suite, and also provided as an example base for new adapters.